# Not able to add a timestamp column to end of a sql table

Tags: mysql

I tried to add a column at end of the table `assestbl`

```
ALTER TABLE  `assestbl` ADD  `timestamp` VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

but its showing an error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' at line 1

Comment: shouldn;t the datatype be datetime rather than VARCHAR

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1) syntax error in datatype, `varchar` needs defined length: `VARCHAR(LEN)`

once you fix that you get something like `invalid default value for 'timestamp'`:

2) `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` can only be applied to temporal datatypes (DATE,TIME,DATETIME,TIMESTAMP and YEAR).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply,the first part worked but got stck in the second partALTER TABLE  `assestbl` ADD  `timestamp` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

MySQL said: 

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'timestamp'

Comment: if i dont add  DEFAULT  as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP how can i add the time of update automatically when table is updated .. just add a varchar column and use something like insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values (getdate());

Comment: to use DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, you need a column of one of the following datatypes: DATE,TIME,DATETIME,TIMESTAMP and YEAR. As in *ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN `timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP*

Comment: VARCHAR is a string type. You'll find it beneficial, in the long run, to use an appropriate data type to store a timestamp. It comes in handy for things like sorting by the timestamp or selecting records based on a date and/or time.